# "Unable to instantiate fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

In the error report below, it says it can't find fragment "com.android.myproject.ad" - which is VERY confusing for me because there's no "ad" class or object in the project. The only cause for this could be the AdMob library/SDK.

Has anyone else seen this with AdMob?
I checked the version of AdMob SDK that I am using and it is the latest (rev. 8)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.myproject/com.android.myproject.ActivityMain}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.android.myproject.ad: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2117)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.android.myproject.ad: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at com.android.myproject.ActivityMain.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.android.myproject.ad
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
```

The AdMob banner is made visible through XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- widgets like buttons and stuff -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bannersLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

        <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

To protect my app from this nasty problem, is there a better way to show AdMob ads (if AdMob is even the problem).

Comment: You you have the AdMob SDK included in the libs/ folder of your project? Or if you are referencing it externally, did you go to the Order & Export tab and export the SDK to make sure it gets bundled into your compiled .apk?

Comment: Eric - yes, the "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar" is shown in the "Order and Export" tab. My app works great - but this one error report is bugging me because I suspect the error is in AdMob.

Comment: So the AdMob SDK has an Ad interface, but it lives in com.google.ads, not com.android.myproject. Are you sure you don't have an ad object in com.android.myproject?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but you can try [creating your AdView in code](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#addadview).

Comment: I am certain that there's no "ad" class in my project. I did a search which resulted in 0 hits.